# Is slicknav really obsolete?

Tags: menu, mobile

The slicknav mobile extension classes itself as Obsolete when we load it into our extensions. https://civicrm.org/extensions/slicknav-web-responsive-admin-menu.

Is this really true? And if so, is it known what it would take to make it current again?

Or is there some other way of having a mobile responsive menu with Civicrm?

We are also looking at the CiviMobile app, which is really really cool! In fact it may make a mobile menu quite obsolete, although there are some parts of Civi we'd like to access (such as pledges and projects) on a mobile device that CiviMobile can't.

We're with latest Drupal 7 and Civicrm 5.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it was made obsolete when another menu system was brought in: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13582

You could try the shoreditch theme: https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful!